# How can I set up an off grid home phone network

Tags: networking, phone

Can I set up a home phone networking system (strictly within the house)( not intended for making REAL phone calls)

So let's say... For a post shtf scenario... That I have a large home. If I'm on one end of the house, and so and so is on the other end of the house. I need to get a quick message to them without walking down 3 flights of stairs and across the house. Can I set up , say, 4 home phones... Into some sort of networking modem (no internet, just electricity) that would enable me to make phone calls from room to room to room? A basic layout or explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your question is off-topic. Computer networking is [on-topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic) here, but not telephone systems/networks.

Answer (score 1):

They make Dect 6.0 based cordless home phone systems with up to 5 handsets that usually can also do handset to handset calls/intercom. Sounds like a much simpler solution to me. I've had one for years and works great.

One Example:
http://www.vtechphones.com/telephones/shop-by-bundle/5-handsets

Answer (score 0):

In telephone parlance, a small privately-owned telephone switch that supports multiple local phone lines (like multiple extensions in a small office) is called a PBX (Private Branch eXchange). A small office PBX can let you plug in multiple analog phones (or, for that matter, some let you do digital or Ethernet VoIP phones), each with their own extension number, and usually connects to a small number of real phone lines to the local telephone carrier company (but this part is optional; you can still make calls from one extension to another even if your real lines to the phone company are disconnected).

If you've ever been at a business where you had to "dial 9 for an outside line", you were using a PBX.

[Here's one on Amazon for $65.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015MIQ12A)